# How can I determine all the codepoints that do not have glyphs in a font using FreeType?

Tags: fonts, freetype, freetype2

This question is closely related to

[Is there a way to programmatically determine if a font file has a specific Unicode Glyph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicode)

However, I am looking for a solution that does not use the Windows API. Freetype in particular looks promising, and I was wondering if anyone familiar with it could provide pointers.

Basically, I'd like to, given a font, calculate a mapping from character map to a sequence of codepoints without glyphs for that character map.

Answer (score 3):

With FreeType in particular, you may use the [FT_Get_Char_Index](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Get_Char_Index) function. This function returns a glyphID of 0 to indicate an unmapped glyph.

In more general terms: first you'd need to select a Character Mapping table (some fonts include multiple maps for different platforms or different purposes under a single platform), then build a dictionary from the explicitly-mapped glyphs, and test against that.