# Detecting glyphs occurrences in any fonts

Tags: .net, flash, winapi, fonts, glyph

I'm writing a small .NET application that can produce SWF files, and I need to support Unicode fonts. I don't know the things on it and font rendering well, so I understand that I've made some blunders while writing my application: many fonts installed on my Windows don't support Unicode characters so I can see hollow squares only instead of the glyphs. My supposition is using of proper font substitution while rendering the SWF files that could contain embedded glyphs. First of all, I must determine whether a glyph is present in the necessary font. I've found a [partial solution of such test here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicode), though it doesn't seem to be the thing I want to achieve because the sample operates for Unicode ranges only. But I've paid attention on Windows' Charmap application: it can hide missing glyphs. I tried to explore how `charmap` does the check with Dependency Walker to analyze its import table, but I didn't find anything instead of some GDI++ font  functions. I don't know what to do and I'm very confused. :(

Please suggest the direction I should look in for. It could be a WinAPI or .NET 2.0 (not even .NET 3.0) suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've found the solution at the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/FontGlyphSet.aspx) myself.