# How can I determine if a font has a glyph for a given character?

Tags: .net, fonts, glyph

How can I determine from the .NET runtime if, for a given font, if it has the glyph for a character? I want to switch the font to Arial Unicode MS if I have text that the specified font does not have a glyph for (very common for CJK).

**Update:** I'm looking for a C# (ie all managed code) solution. I think [GlyphTypeface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be what I need but I can't see a way in it to ask if a given character has a glyph. You can get the entire map back, but I assume that would be an expensive call.

Comment: Many topics on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633495/detecting-glyphs-occurrences-in-any-fonts?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025740/c-check-for-unsupported-characters-glyphs-in-a-font?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730544/is-there-a-glyph-not-found-character?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some unicode tools and the technique I use is getting the map and chache it
for each font used.

```
IDictionary<int, ushort> characterMap = GlyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap
```

will give you the defined glyph index per codepoint.

[msdn ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.charactertoglyphmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (characterMap.ContainsKey(CodePoint))
    glyphExists = true;
else
    glyphExists = false;
```

Comment: I haven't used .net in years but isn't `glyphExists = characterMap.ContainsKey(codePoint);` valid? (and more succinct)

Comment: @Suragch code is a language, when explaining, verbosity wins against concision in my spirit I guess...