# How to display Unicode UTF-8 in RDLC

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I want to display a UTF-8 character in RDLC Reports. Basically a small triangle, in RDLC report.

I changed this line of code:

```
 CarDisplayField=Char.ConvertFromUtf32(9653);
```

but the column header it self is not getting displayed?

Comment: Then the font you're using does not contain that glyph.

Comment: By searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274311/checking-if-certain-characters-are-supported-by-a-font