# Display supported characters of a FON font

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, gdi, bitmap-fonts

I would like to be able get the supported characters of a FON font

i am loading the font with AddFontResourceEx from the gdi32.dll

Comment: It took me quite a while to recall that FON might be a BITMAP font and you are trying a get a LIST of all characters that are represented within.  Correct?

Comment: yep, i think it is a bitmap font

Comment: Right, dates back from the previous century.  A device font.  .NET doesn't do device fonts anymore, there's little point with TrueType around.

Comment: i was asked to add some error checking to detect when a user enters not supported characters for these fonts we have.

Comment: @user1120187 - According to wiki the fon file is just a collection of bitmap images, so if you can determine the format, you may actually be able to get what you're after. I did a little googling for you but was unable to (quickly) find anything useful.

Comment: been trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439551/get-supported-characters-of-a-font-in-c-sharp) but havent had any success yet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Fallout has taken FON format from Windows: http://falloutmods.wikia.com/wiki/FON_File_Format