# how to check which out of all installed fonts supports characters from given language?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, fonts

Hi I would like to use for each language proper font family. I mean that not all fonts support characters from given language (Japanese, Russina, etc) in C#.

So is it possible to automatically take the correct font family when we know the language in which we would like to display something?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod

Answer (score 0):

yes you can easily accomplish this:

I prefer using Page_Init rather then page load to make sure it loads first.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string languageToUse = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

    if (languageToUse == "en")
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<link href='/css/en.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />"));
        else if (languageToUse == "de")
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<link href='/css/de.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />"));
    }
```

inside the css you write the font family you want to use

Comment: But it's not a solution, in this case i need to declare which fonts it should use in which cases. So if for some language I don't declare any fonts it will display characters not correctly. I would like to system take care about changing fonts..