# WPF FontFallback not working

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts, textblock

On Windows 10 I have the following WPF TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe Mdl2 Assets">Hello World!</TextBlock>
```

The text is rendered as empty rectangles (undefined glyphs).

My understanding from [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily(v=vs.110).aspx) is that a fallback should be substituted.

> Font Fallback
>
> Font fallback refers to the automatic substitution of a font other than the font that is selected by the client application. There are two primary reasons why font fallback is invoked:
>
> •The font that is specified by the client application does not exist on the system.
>
> •The font that is specified by the client application does not contain the
> glyphs that are required to render text.

Is it possible to make this work without resorting to checking manually as in [Is there a way to programmatically determine if a font file has a specific Unicode Glyph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103725/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-if-a-font-file-has-a-specific-unicod)